# How to combine two html form input tag's value and store it into model object of C#

Tags: c#, html, .net

This is my html form

```
@model Demo.Models.ContactU

<form asp-action="Create">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-12 bottom-margin-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First name" aria-label="First name">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-12 bottom-margin-5">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name" aria-label="Last name">
    </div>
</form>
```

And this is my model

```
public partial class ContactU
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**I want to Combine First name and Last name into whole name and store it into my database**

Controller method

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Contact(ContactU contactU)
{
    _dbContext.ContactUs.Add(contactU);
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: Typically you don't use your entities directy in the View, you use a ViewModel that manages the data however you want.

Comment: Can u explain it how can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add name attributes to your inputs: `name="firstName"` and `name="lastName"`. Than you should add `FirstName` and `LastName` properties to your model. And if you want to access those as a single property, you can use get only property:

```
public class Contact
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string FullName => $"{FirstName} {LastName}";
}
```

What you want to do(map two inputs into single property) is also possible, but you will have to write custom `ModelBinder`, but it will be more complex and not sure if you want to go into that direction.

Comment: As @Crowcoder suggests, What If i create One ViewContactUs Class which have Property of FirstName and LastName and One another Repository Class(IDk this is a proper name for this class or not) Which accept the object of ViewContactUs and return ContactUs Objact then i can directly store that into my DB?

Comment: @Dhruvil that's totally fine and depending on project size it might be even preferable. (Repository class you talking about usually called Entity class, so you have ViewModel class and Entity class). But honestly, think twice before storing First name and Last name combined into one column. From two columns you can get full name easily. But from one column it's very hard/impossible to get First/Last names separately, as sooner or later you will face users with names which have more than two words.